# <a href="#"> the style changes on phone, when tapped

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an :active style on my "a" tags, but on a mobile phone it's not the same, that I wrote.

I have done the following:

```css
a {
 display: block;
 background-color: lightblue;
 width: 100px;
 color: black;
}

a:active {
 background-color: skyblue;
}
```

It should do the following:
Have "a" tags, that are have a light blue background and when I tap on it it's background color change to sky blue. Yes it happens, BUT if I add a href="ANYTHING", then, when I tap on it it's background color is a bit darker, than sky blue, and the text's color changes to a bit blueish.

Sorry for my English, I tried my best.

Comment: What does your links contain ? ... If numbers, try `a[href^='tel']`, as phones often have a built-in style for numbers that can be interpreted as a phone number

Comment: Also try and add the `a:hover` and `a:focus` pseudo classes, as a tap (the first one) might put the link in a hover or focus state

Comment: And btw, do note, you are suppose to provide a [mcve], that reproduce the issue, so we can see its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set custom styles for the rest of the pseudo classes that are related to the  element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link

Try adding visited to the list like this:

```
a:active, a:visited {
    background-color: skyblue;
}
```

Comment: A note on this is that adding a:any-link will add that styling to the element whether it's been visited or not. As found on the MDN page linked in the answer.

Comment: None of the pseudo classes solve my problem. I think that tapping on a phone is different than clicking on a mouse, because if I hold down left click on a computer, than it wont select the word, on the other hand phone does. I know that there is a way to change the style of the scrolling bar, or the color of the text's background when its selected. Is there anything that can solve my problem in this way or on a more difficult way?